Is there any cost which snowflake charges to provider account to host snowflke native app to snowflake market place?
I am working on creating a snowflake native app using snowpark container services and want to host that app on snowflake marketplace, will snowflake going to charge me anything to host my app on marketplace, if yes then what will be that, is it going to be revenue sharing ?
is it going to be revenue sharing ?

The revenue model is up to you. It can be shared where funds (such as a monthly subscription) are collected by Snowflake, or you can have your own charging mechanism (make it available as free on the Marketplace).  There is not a fee to host it, but you can consume CPU credits along the way.
